# Count of visits to a given state of a Markov chain.

Tags: markov-chains

While studying Markov processes, I faced to the following task. Please help to solve.

We have the Markov Chain with two states. This Markov chain is shown here: [image]

The probabilities of transitions $p$ and $q$ are known. The initial state is $1$ with probability = $1$. A walk along this chain is started and it is interrupted as soon as state $2$ has been visited $n$ times. Let the random variable $\xi$ be the number of visits to state $1$ before the interruption. How can we find the variance of $\xi$?

Upd. The first thought I had was to represent $\xi$ as a random variable with Negative binomial distribution. But this is incorrect because different sequences of states 1, 2 have different probability of realizations.

The next attempt was like this. Let $F_m(k)$ be the probability of visiting the state 1 $k$ times with interrupt condition is the second state is visited $m$ times. Then variance of $\xi$ is $V(x) = E \xi^2 - E^2 \xi$, when
$$
E \xi = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k F_n(k), E \xi^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^2 F_n(k) .
$$

$F_n(k)$ can be expressed using recursion. Recursion base is
$$
F_1(k) = (1-p)^{k-1} p .
$$
For $F_n(k), n > 1$ we get
$$
F_n (k) = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} F_{n-1} (k-j) (1-p)^{j-1} p + F_{n-1}(k)(1-q).
$$
I tried to switch from recursion to an closet formula, but power terms appear together with Bernoulli numbers and it becomes completely unclear how to count $E \xi, E \xi^2$.

Comment: This shouldn't be solved as a Markov chain question. It is difficult to find this quantity for a general Markov chain, but here, we can express $\xi$ as a sum of Geometric random variables. Try it.

Comment: @MishaLavrov , please, can you tell us in more detail what you mean. I tried to interpret $xi$ as Negative binomial distribution random variable . but I faced to this problem due to random walk, different sequences  of the states have different probability of realization.

Comment: If that's the case, then you should edit your question, because your question led me to believe you had not tried anything. Write up what you attempted and where you got stuck.

Comment: @MishaLavrov , I added my attempts with edit. But, as you can see, I have reached a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

The negative binomial approach is the correct one here, it just needs some modification.

Let $X_1$ be the number of times state $1$ is visited before visiting state $2$ for the first time. Then, for $2 \le i \le n$, let $X_i$ be the number of times state $1$ is visited between the $(i-1)^{\text{th}}$ and $i^{\text{th}}$ visit to state $2$. We have:

- $X_1 \sim \text{Geometric}(p)$ (with the convention that the range of a geometric distribution starts at $1$). We have $\Pr[X_1 = k] = p(1-p)^{k-1}$ for $k=1, 2, 3, \dots$
- For $i \ge 2$, $X_i$ has a very similar distribution if we go from $2$ back to $1$, but we can also stay at $2$ and get $X_i=0$. We have $\Pr[X_i = 0] = 1-q$ and $\Pr[X_i = k] = pq(1-p)^{k-1}$ for $k=1, 2, 3, \dots$. A useful way to think of $X_i$ is as a mixture distribution: it is $0$ with probability $1-q$ and $\text{Geometric}(p)$ with probability $q$.

We have $\text{Var}[X_1] = \frac{1-p}{p^2}$ by the usual formula, but for $X_2, \dots, X_n$ a bit more work needs to be done to compute $\text{Var}[X_i]$. One approach is to condition the first step to compute $\mathbb E[X_i]$ and $\mathbb E[X_i^2]$ (in which case the law of total expectation can be used).

Since $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are independent, we have $$\text{Var}[\xi] = \text{Var}[X_1] + \dots + \text{Var}[X_n].$$